# Two models with 2 the same relationship with each other in RAILS 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Here's the scenario:

An HMO has_many USER (these are the members of the HMO).
A User belongs to HMO.

A USER *==Owner of HMO==* has_one HMO.
HMO belongs_to USER.

Now, when I query Hmo.first.users the OWNER is also included in the list.
How can I implement this on RAILS ActiveRecord relationship?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between user and owner of HMO?
If you have a boolean flag for the owner, then you can use something like this to get users without owner:

```
has_many :users, -> { where owner: false }, class_name: 'User'
```

[Documentation: Scopes for has_many](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many)

Comment: actually there's no difference, they save the same attribute. Does it mean I need to add an attribute :owner and default value will be false.

Comment: Do you have owner_id saved in the HMO model?

Comment: I do have user_id in the HMO model. do I need to make alias for this one? Actually its already working thanks to your idea. I just twisted it. By the default I have a user_type: 0 that means 'user' and 1 for 'owner'

Comment: Then you do not have to do anything else :) just remember to make my answer as the one that helped you